# Does AWS support DBF files or Samba Shares?

Tags: amazon-web-services, database, amazon-dynamodb

We have DBF files running in our local network. It's on an Ubuntu Server running Samba shares. The DBF files are used by our in-house system running on xBase.

Now we're moving everything to Amazon Web Services. I was wondering if **AWS has an infrastructure available to run DBF files?** Where we can store data and still access it from our xBase system. I was looking into DynamoDB but I don't know if it will work as needed. **Or does it have a special infrastructure to run Samba-like shares?**

My last option would probably to run a Samba Server in an EC2 instance.

Any advise please.

Thanks.

Comment: Amazon gives you virtual servers, you can run whatever you want. Generally the recommendation is that you should read documentation first, try it / try solving it yourself second, then ask here third if you have a problem that needs solving.

Comment: @Tim Went through the documentations I could find. I was wondering if I missed anything. DynamoDB doesn't seem to fit. We're running this in EC2 instead. DBFs are old, was expecting much support anyway. Thanks.

Comment: I've never heard of DBF. If you can run it on a physical computer you can probably run it in AWS. While they do have a lot of database services just spin up a VM and run whatever you want. You could probably find a way to run Windows 3.11 if you tried hard enough.

Comment: Specify what kind of DB engine of your DBF,  the question give too little details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer for AWS services that load DBF : NO

Longer answer : RDS services doesn't support DBF file types. One issues of DBF is, there is no standard. A dbf can be from ANY database engine, format is varied. If you want CORRECT answer, you must specify what DB engine it is, and not all db engine will recognise them.

If you have an apps or DB engine that read the DBF, you just put those APPS inside EC2 instance, then throw the DBF file into EBS storage.  You can host any Linux engine and load samba server, just make sure you put your DBF into EBS, NOT  instance-store.

AWS start rolling out file server call "Elastic file system" in US, but there is no guarantee that it will work for your apps, if it doesn't support the API.